# Slight point strokes in ggplot points

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following:

library(ggplot2)

```
df = data.frame(x = rep(0,9), y = rep(0,9), alp = c(1:8/20,1))
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y, alpha=alp), size = 20, col = 'red') + 
  theme_minimal() + facet_wrap(~ alp) + guides(alpha = F)
```

[image]

As you can see there are feint outlines.  It makes overlaying many low-transparency points look a bit like frogspawn.  Is this just a Mac thing?  Any idea how to remove it?

Comment: Are you talking about the very faint border of the point itself or are you talking about the underline of the background underneath the semi-transparent point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default point shape for ggplot2 is `pch = 19`. It's not one of those points where the colour of its border and its inside can be controlled separately; for instance, in the following, `fill = 'black'` has no effect.

```
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(x =runif(1000), y = runif(1000))

p = ggplot(df) + 
geom_point(aes(x, y), alpha = .1, size = 5, fill = 'black', colour = 'red') +                                        
  theme_bw() 
p
```

[image]

Yet the point does have a boundary line. The line's width can be changed with `stroke`; as follows:

```
p = ggplot(df) + 
geom_point(aes(x, y), stroke = 2, alpha = .1, size = 5, fill = 'black', colour = 'red') +                                        
  theme_bw() 
p
```

[image]

Unfortunately, setting stroke to zero will not remove the boundary line; it seems there is a lower limit.

To remove the boundary line, use one of the shapes that has a border that can be manipulated; for instance, `shape = 21`. Set its "fill" to red and its "colour" to transparent.

```
p = ggplot(df) + 
geom_point(aes(x, y), shape = 21, alpha = .1, size = 5, fill = 'red', colour = 'transparent') +                                      
  theme_bw() 
p
```

[image]

Comment: Whether the boundary vanishes when `stroke` is set to zero also depends on how you print the plot object: for example, when using `grDevices::svg()` to output an `svg`, the boundary disappears with `stroke = 0`.  (I checked that with chromium; with SVG's appearance might also depend on your viewer.)

Comment: Also, if yo use `grDevices::png()` with `type = "cairo"`, the boundary disappears.

Answer (score 1):

`see::geom_point2` draws points without this border.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(see)

df = data.frame(x = rep(0,9), y = rep(0,9), alp = c(1:8/20,1))

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point2(aes(x, y, alpha=alp), size = 20, col = 'red') + 
  theme_minimal() + facet_wrap(~ alp) + guides(alpha = F)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>