# R ggplot2: How to change the thickness of a dot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a plot with ggplot2 in R and I want to change the thickness of my dots. I am using circles without a center (shape = 1) and I want to change the thickness of the lines. How do I do this, please? I am using geom_point

Size changes how large the dot/circle is, it does not charge how thick of a border there is around the dot

Comment: There is `size` argument you can modify

Comment: Size sets the size of the entire point, stroke sets the width of the outline for outlined shapes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was inspired in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081159/slight-point-strokes-in-ggplot-points#38088664) to a similar question.

Use aesthetics `stroke` with small values, either zero or close to zero such as `0.1`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(0, 4), y = rep(0, 4), stroke = (0:3)/4)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y, stroke = stroke),
             shape = 1,
             size = 20, colour = 'red') +
  facet_wrap(~ stroke)
```

[image]

---

## Edit

Answering the comments below, here is an example of the use of [`scale_discrete_manual`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3507#issuecomment-526212978) to change the stroke.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
})

df <- data.frame(x = rep(0, 4), y = rep(0, 4), stroke = (0:3)/4)

f <- factor(df$stroke)
vals <- setNames(c(3, 2, 4, 1), f)

df %>%
  mutate(stroke = factor(stroke)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y, stroke = stroke),
             shape = 1,
             size = 20, colour = 'red') +
  scale_discrete_manual(aesthetics = "stroke", values = vals) +
  facet_wrap(~ stroke)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to scale the strokes? Like `scale_stroke_manual`?

Comment: @drmariod You can use [`scale_discrete_manual`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3507#issuecomment-526212978) with `aesthetics = "stroke"` and then change the `values` argument.

Comment: Cool, might be interesting to update your post to include this... But your answer did not get the deserved likes yet. :-(